# Inserting +10,000 data from ec2 to rds postgres is sooooo solow

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, flask-sqlalchemy, amazon-rds

I am inserting huge amount of data from ec2 to rds postgres.
ec2 reads data from S3, and format the data then inserts to rds.

Using pyhton3.8, flask and flask_sqlalchemy

ec2 is based on Sydney, rds is based on west2.

Each insert is like taking 30 secs, that may take over 1~2 days to complete all inserting.

When I try in my local to local postgres, it's done in 5mins.

Anyway I can improve the performance? Like increasing ec2 instance's size?

I googled and found put ec2 and rds into same region may increase performance, but need more opinions from you guys

Comment: I would be a bit worried about the bill for September.

Comment: Was it initially fast, and then went slower? What is the size of the Amazon RDS PostgreSQL instance? If it is a T-family instance, what does the monitoring show for CPU/credits? How are you inserting the data (is it an INSERT with one row at a time)? Are you saying that your Amazon EC2 instance is in a **different region** to the Amazon RDS database?

Comment: Why are you running the EC2 in Australia, and the RDS in the United States? The data transfer fees are going to be super expensive, and the networking latency is going to be terrible. Run them in the same AWS region! Of course sending data half way around the world is going to be slower than sending data between two computers in the same building!

Answer (score 0):

I was reading about an article [Inserting a billion rows in SQLite under a minute](https://avi.im/blag/2021/fast-sqlite-inserts/) may help you.

Personally i did not use EC2 but if you can change your database configuration that article still can help you. It based on optimizing the database configuration for inserting too much data.